# Inserting URLs visited in chrome to a MySQL db using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-chrome

I would like to have a Chrome Extension which will keep inserting the URLs visited by the user in a MySQL table.

**background.html**

```
<script>
var myURL = "nourl";

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  myURL = tab.url;
});

dataparam = "url="+myURL;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://domainname.com/insertdb.php",
        data: dataparam,
        error:function() {
                alert("sorry")
        },
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
    });


</script>
```

insertdb.php

```
<?php
$val=$_REQUEST['url'];

// Inserting $val in the db code goes here.

?>
```

I am new to javascript and this code doesn seem to work. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you try to move  `dataparam` and the ajax call inside the function that stores the url?

Comment: Yup I tried doing that, no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain cross-origin permission.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html